# Is it possible to load contact pictures using google's people api?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-people-api

I'm trying to find my way around Google's People API. So far, I've been able to load the contact groups using

```
try{
    contact_groups = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        people.contactGroups.list({
            auth: oauth2Client
        }, function(error, response){
            if(!error){
                resolve(response);
            }else{
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}catch(error){
    throw error;
};
```

where `people` is the instantiated `google-api-nodejs-client` `people(v1)` object.

I'm trying to get a profile picture for the user's contacts. How do I load the public profile picture or a placeholder for each of the contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using Google's people API.

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  'CLIENT_ID',
  'CLIENT_SECRET'
  'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback'
);

router.get('/signin', function(req, res, next){
  var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    scope: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'
    ]
  });

  res.redirect(url);
});

router.get('/google/callback', function(req, res, next){
  oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, async function(err, tokens){
    if(!err){
      oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;

      try{
        var contacts = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          people.people.connections.list({
            resourceName: 'people/me',
            auth: oauth2Client,
            personFields: 'names,photos'
        }, function(error, response){
          if(!error){
            resolve(response);
        }else{
          reject(error);
        }
      })
    });
  }catch(error){
    throw error;
  }
});
```